# HTML/PHP/JQUERY - Change text Input type field in form to selector field when the right country is selected, otherwise keep field as textbox input

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a site in the making, currently I want to be able to do the following:

If the user selects "United States" in the country selector.

Then (field9[state]) becomes a select form that has the name of the US states)

else if user selects any other country from the country selector

Then (field9[state] stays as a textbox [input=text] and the user is able to type their state )

Is this possible? if it is, how would i execute this...

Thank you guys.

here is the code that i currently have for the country and state:

```
<li class="w30">
                                <label class="form-label" for="field11" id="lblfield11">
                                    Country<span class="required-sign"> *</span>                                    </label>
                                <div class="form-field">
                                            <select class="jomNameTips tipRight select validate-country required" name="field11" id="field11" original-title="Your country">

        <option selected="selected" value="">Country</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_UNITEDSTATES">United States</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_AFGHANISTAN">Afghanistan</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_ALANDISLANDS">Åland Islands</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_ALBANIA">Albania</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_ALGERIA">Algeria</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_AMERICANSAMOA">American Samoa</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_ANDORRA">Andorra</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_ANGOLA">Angola</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_ANGUILLA">Anguilla</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_ANTARCTICA">Antarctica</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_ANTIGUAANDBARBUDA">Antigua And Barbuda</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_ARGENTINA">Argentina</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_ARMENIA">Armenia</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_ARUBA">Aruba</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_AUSTRALIA">Australia</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_AUSTRIA">Austria</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_AZERBAIJAN">Azerbaijan</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_BAHAMAS">Bahamas</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_BAHRAIN">Bahrain</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_BANGLADESH">Bangladesh</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_BARBADOS">Barbados</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_BELARUS">Belarus</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_BELGIUM">Belgium</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_BELIZE">Belize</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_BENIN">Benin</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_BERMUDA">Bermuda</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_BHUTAN">Bhutan</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_BOLIVIAPLURINATIONALSTATEOF">Bolivia, PLURINATIONAL STATE OF</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_BOSNIAANDHERZEGOVINA">Bosnia And Herzegovina</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_BOTSWANA">Botswana</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_BOUVETISLAND">Bouvet Island</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_BRAZIL">Brazil</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_BRITISHINDIANOCEANTERRITORY">British Indian Ocean Territory</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_BRUNEIDARUSSALAM">Brunei Darussalam</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_BULGARIA">Bulgaria</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_BURKINAFASO">Burkina Faso</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_BURUNDI">Burundi</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_CAMBODIA">Cambodia</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_CAMEROON">Cameroon</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_CANADA">Canada</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_CAPEVERDE">Cape Verde</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_CAYMANISLANDS">Cayman Islands</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_CENTRALAFRICANREPUBLIC">Central African Republic</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_CHAD">Chad</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_CHILE">Chile</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_CHINA">China</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_CHRISTMASISLAND">Christmas Island</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_COCOSKEELINGISLANDS">Cocos (KEELING) Islands</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_COLOMBIA">Colombia</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_COMOROS">Comoros</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_CONGO">Congo</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_CONGOTHEDEMOCRATICREPUBLICOFTHE">Congo, The Democratic Republic Of The</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_COOKISLANDS">Cook Islands</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_COSTARICA">Costa Rica</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_CROATIA">Croatia</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_CTEDIVOIRE">CÃ"te D'Ivoire</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_CUBA">Cuba</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_CYPRUS">Cyprus</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_CZECHREPUBLIC">Czech Republic</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_DENMARK">Denmark</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_DJIBOUTI">Djibouti</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_DOMINICA">Dominica</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_DOMINICANREPUBLIC">Dominican Republic</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_ECUADOR">Ecuador</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_EGYPT">Egypt</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_ELSALVADOR">El Salvador</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_EQUATORIALGUINEA">Equatorial Guinea</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_ERITREA">Eritrea</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_ESTONIA">Estonia</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_ETHIOPIA">Ethiopia</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_FALKLANDISLANDSMALVINAS">Falkland Islands (MALVINAS)</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_FAROEISLANDS">Faroe Islands</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_FIJI">Fiji</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_FINLAND">Finland</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_FRANCE">France</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_FRENCHGUIANA">French Guiana</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_FRENCHPOLYNESIA">French Polynesia</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_FRENCHSOUTHERNTERRITORIES">French Southern Territories</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_GABON">Gabon</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_GAMBIA">Gambia</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_GEORGIA">Georgia</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_GERMANY">Germany</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_GHANA">Ghana</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_GIBRALTAR">Gibraltar</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_GREECE">Greece</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_GREENLAND">Greenland</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_GRENADA">Grenada</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_GUADELOUPE">Guadeloupe</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_GUAM">Guam</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_GUATEMALA">Guatemala</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_GUERNSEY">Guernsey</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_GUINEA">Guinea</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_GUINEABISSAU">Guinea-Bissau</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_GUYANA">Guyana</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_HAITI">Haiti</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_HEARDISLANDANDMCDONALDISLANDS">Heard Island And Mcdonald Islands</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_HOLYSEEVATICANCITYSTATE">Holy See (VATICAN CITY STATE)</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_HONDURAS">Honduras</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_HONGKONG">Hong Kong</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_HUNGARY">Hungary</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_ICELAND">Iceland</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_INDIA">India</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_INDONESIA">Indonesia</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_IRANISLAMICREPUBLICOF">Iran, Islamic Republic Of</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_IRAQ">Iraq</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_IRELAND">Ireland</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_ISLEOFMAN">Isle Of Man</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_ISRAEL">Israel</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_ITALY">Italy</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_JAMAICA">Jamaica</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_JAPAN">Japan</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_JERSEY">Jersey</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_JORDAN">Jordan</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_KAZAKHSTAN">Kazakhstan</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_KENYA">Kenya</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_KIRIBATI">Kiribati</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_KOREADEMOCRATICPEOPLESREPUBLICOF">Korea, Democratic People's Republic Of</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_KOREAREPUBLICOF">Korea, Republic Of</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_KUWAIT">Kuwait</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_KYRGYZSTAN">Kyrgyzstan</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_LAOPEOPLESDEMOCRATICREPUBLIC">Lao People's Democratic Republic</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_LATVIA">Latvia</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_LEBANON">Lebanon</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_LESOTHO">Lesotho</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_LIBERIA">Liberia</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_LIBYANARABJAMAHIRIYA">Libyan Arab Jamahiriya</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_LIECHTENSTEIN">Liechtenstein</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_LITHUANIA">Lithuania</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_LUXEMBOURG">Luxembourg</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_MACAO">Macao</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_MACEDONIATHEFORMERYUGOSLAVREPUBLICOF">Macedonia, The Former Yugoslav Republic Of</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_MADAGASCAR">Madagascar</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_MALAWI">Malawi</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_MALAYSIA">Malaysia</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_MALDIVES">Maldives</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_MALI">Mali</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_MALTA">Malta</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_MARSHALLISLANDS">Marshall Islands</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_MARTINIQUE">Martinique</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_MAURITANIA">Mauritania</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_MAURITIUS">Mauritius</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_MAYOTTE">Mayotte</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_MEXICO">Mexico</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_MICRONESIAFEDERATEDSTATESOF">Micronesia, Federated States Of</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_MOLDOVAREPUBLICOF">Moldova, Republic Of</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_MONACO">Monaco</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_MONGOLIA">Mongolia</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_MONTENEGRO">Montenegro</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_MONTSERRAT">Montserrat</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_MOROCCO">Morocco</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_MOZAMBIQUE">Mozambique</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_MYANMAR">Myanmar</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_NAMIBIA">Namibia</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_NAURU">Nauru</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_NEPAL">Nepal</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_NETHERLANDS">Netherlands</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_NETHERLANDSANTILLES">Netherlands Antilles</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_NEWCALEDONIA">New Caledonia</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_NEWZEALAND">New Zealand</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_NICARAGUA">Nicaragua</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_NIGER">Niger</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_NIGERIA">Nigeria</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_NIUE">Niue</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_NORFOLKISLAND">Norfolk Island</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_NORTHERNMARIANAISLANDS">Northern Mariana Islands</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_NORWAY">Norway</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_OMAN">Oman</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_PAKISTAN">Pakistan</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_PALAU">Palau</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_PALESTINIANTERRITORYOCCUPIED">Palestinian Territory, Occupied</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_PANAMA">Panama</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_PAPUANEWGUINEA">Papua New Guinea</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_PARAGUAY">Paraguay</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_PERU">Peru</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_PHILIPPINES">Philippines</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_PITCAIRN">Pitcairn</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_POLAND">Poland</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_PORTUGAL">Portugal</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_PUERTORICO">Puerto Rico</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_QATAR">Qatar</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_REUNION">Reunion</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_ROMANIA">Romania</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_RUSSIANFEDERATION">Russian Federation</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_RWANDA">Rwanda</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_SAINTBARTHELEMY">Saint Barthelemy</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_SAINTHELENAASCENSIONANDTRISTANDACUNHA">Saint Helena, Ascension And Tristan Da Cunha</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_SAINTKITTSANDNEVIS">Saint Kitts And Nevis</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_SAINTLUCIA">Saint Lucia</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_SAINTMARTIN">Saint Martin</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_SAINTPIERREANDMIQUELON">Saint Pierre And Miquelon</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_SAINTVINCENTANDTHEGRENADINES">Saint Vincent And The Grenadines</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_SAMOA">Samoa</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_SANMARINO">San Marino</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_SAOTOMEANDPRINCIPE">Sao Tome And Principe</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_SAUDIARABIA">Saudi Arabia</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_SENEGAL">Senegal</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_SERBIA">Serbia</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_SEYCHELLES">Seychelles</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_SIERRALEONE">Sierra Leone</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_SINGAPORE">Singapore</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_SLOVAKIA">Slovakia</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_SLOVENIA">Slovenia</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_SOLOMONISLANDS">Solomon Islands</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_SOMALIA">Somalia</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_SOUTHAFRICA">South Africa</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_SOUTHGEORGIAANDTHESOUTHSANDWICHISLANDS">South Georgia And The South Sandwich Islands</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_SPAIN">Spain</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_SRILANKA">Sri Lanka</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_SUDAN">Sudan</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_SURINAME">Suriname</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_SVALBARDANDJANMAYEN">Svalbard And Jan Mayen</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_SWAZILAND">Swaziland</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_SWEDEN">Sweden</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_SWITZERLAND">Switzerland</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_SYRIANARABREPUBLIC">Syrian Arab Republic</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_TAIWANPROVINCEOFCHINA">Taiwan, Province Of China</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_TAJIKISTAN">Tajikistan</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_TANZANIAUNITEDREPUBLICOF">Tanzania, United Republic Of</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_THAILAND">Thailand</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_TIMORLESTE">Timor-Leste</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_TOGO">Togo</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_TOKELAU">Tokelau</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_TONGA">Tonga</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_TRINIDADANDTOBAGO">Trinidad And Tobago</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_TUNISIA">Tunisia</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_TURKEY">Turkey</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_TURKMENISTAN">Turkmenistan</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_TURKSANDCAICOSISLANDS">Turks And Caicos Islands</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_TUVALU">Tuvalu</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_UGANDA">Uganda</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_UKRAINE">Ukraine</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_UNITEDARABEMIRATES">United Arab Emirates</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_UNITEDKINGDOM">United Kingdom</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_UNITEDSTATESMINOROUTLYINGISLANDS">United States Minor Outlying Islands</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_URUGUAY">Uruguay</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_UZBEKISTAN">Uzbekistan</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_VANUATU">Vanuatu</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_VENEZUELABOLIVARIANREPUBLICOF">Venezuela, Bolivarian Republic Of</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_VIETNAM">Vietnam</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_VIRGINISLANDSBRITISH">Virgin Islands, British</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_VIRGINISLANDSUS">Virgin Islands, U.S.</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_WALLISANDFUTUNA">Wallis And Futuna</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_WESTERNSAHARA">Western Sahara</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_YEMEN">Yemen</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_ZAMBIA">Zambia</option>
                <option value="COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_ZIMBABWE">Zimbabwe</option>
            </select>

               </div>
            </li>
            <li class="w30 state">
                                <label class="form-label" for="field9" id="lblfield9">
                                    State                                   </label>
                                <div class="form-field">
                                    <input type="text" class="jomNameTips tipRight jomNameTips tipRight input" size="40" maxlength="100"  name="field9" id="field9" value="" title="Your state" placeholder="State<?php //echo JText::_( 'COM_COMMUNITY_VERIFY_PASSWORD' ); ?>"><span id="errjsusernamemsg" style="display:Assy Mcgee;">&nbsp;</span>




                                </div>
                            </li>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/acviy.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do it is to tie an event to your country drop down list, and then, if US is selected, show a state drop down list and hide the text input.  If US is not selected, hide the state drop down list and show the text input.

I'm using a simplified version of your code.

HTML:

```
<select id="ddlCountry">
    <option value="-1">-- SELECT --</option>
    <option value="0">US</option>
    <option value="1">Other</option>
</select>
<br />
<input type="text" id="txtState" value="" placeholder="state">
<select id="ddlState" class="hidden">
    <option value="Alabama">Alabama</option>
    <option value="Alaska">Alaska</option>
</select>
```

JQuery:

```
$('#ddlCountry').change(function () {
    if ($(this).val() == "0") {
        $('#ddlState').removeClass('hidden');
        $('#txtState').addClass('hidden');
    } else {
        $('#ddlState').addClass('hidden');
        $('#txtState').removeClass('hidden');
    }
});
```

CSS:

```
.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

[Fiddle demo link.](https://jsfiddle.net/0k4vfwya/)

Comment: Funnily enough i ended up using both of the answers in this page to resolve the issue, since one gave the command and the other one gave a class type. Only applying one made the box move and applying the other made the selection box disappear. Once both were input in the "then" part of the code, this made it work like a charm. Thank you!

I appreciate the Fiddle demo Link!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the US_states dropdown with id `select_US_State` and an input field with id `input_state` for other countries:

```
$("select").change(function()
    {
       if($(this).val() == "COM_COMMUNITY_LANG_NAME_UNITEDSTATES")
       {   $("#select_US_State").show();
          $("#input_state").hide(); }
       else
    {
           $("#select_US_State").hide();
          $("#input_state").show();      
    }
    });
```

Comment: This is also the right answer. Funnily enough i ended up using both of the answers in this page to resolve the issue, since one gave the command and the other one gave a class type. Only applying one made the box move and applying the other made the selection box disappear. Once both were input in the "then" part of the code, this made it work like a charm. Thank you!